# Possible to use a voltage level shift IC for Arduino and external IC?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, level-shifting

One of my projects require a 3.3V supply.
Its an audio codec, TIs AIC3254, to be interfaced with Arduino Uno.

The codec requires almost 300mA of current, so was thinking of using a level shifter connected to the 5V output of the Arduino board, which can supply 400mA, instead of using an external supply with LDO.

Can the Arduino 5V output be used efficiently with level shifter? Or external supply is the best option?

Thanks.
PS - Codec schem
[image]

*Ignore the USB part*

Comment: What is this level-shifter you talk of?

Comment: Conceptually, level shifters are for signals, while voltage regulators and dc/dc converters are for supplies.  Since you mention audio beware of noise on the supply.   The USB part you want us to ignore is probably your answer for getting your supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,  a typical level shifter can not be used as a voltage regulator to supply 300 mA of power. They are intended to be used for signals and will likely only source a few mA at best.

You do not need an external power supply, you can use a LDO Linear Voltage Regulator with the Arduino 5V source as the input.